# const_cast failing in c++

Tags: c++, const-cast

```
CallingClass::CallingFunc()
{
    SomeClass obj;
    obj.Construct(*Singleton::GetInstance()); // passing the listener
    // Singleton::GetInstance() returns a static pointer.
    //Singleton is derived from IListener
}

SomeClass::Construct(const IListener &listener)
{
    IListener* pListener = const_cast<IListener*>(&listener);
}
```

After `const_cast` `pListener` is null.
Is it possible to perform such typecasting?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly fails? Do you have problem at compilation time? Runtime? I don't see anything wrong in the `SomeClass::Construct` member function.

Comment: are you serious, a `GetInstance()` that returns a pointer to a **singleton**???? Gheesh, that's the epitomy of ugly code!

Comment: After const_cast pListener is null.

Comment: I think the `const_cast` might have to be moved after the `&` operator, but can't test right now. Before you try to cast away the `const`, you're already asking for the address of a `const` reference, which is strange.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: I am sorry, but isnt that way the singleton is written. I did not understand your concerns.Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: @yogeshsingh Please read this article on why [Singletons are not a good idea](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).  Hopefully that will clear up my concerns.

Comment: @TonyTheLion:Thanks for your reply, I have absolutely no control over Construct Method. its An API of a platform. I have just made an application which passes the singleton reference so that i can handle call back anywhere in the application.what I wanted to know was can we perform const_cast on a static pointer? – yogesh singh 36 secs ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two questions:

1. What are you trying to acheive here?
2. How much control have you got over the code? (i.e. what are you able to change?)

Without wishing to be unkind I would honestly say that it might be better to start again. There are a couple of issues I would have with this code:

Firstly, the Singleton pattern should ensure that only one of a specific object is ever created, therefore it is usually returned by pointer, reference or some derivative thereof (i.e. boost shared pointer etc.) It need not necessarily be const though and the fact that it is here indicates that the author did not intend it to be used in a non-const way.

Second, you're then passing this object by reference into a function. No need. That's the one of the major features (and drawbacks) of the singleton pattern: You can access it from anywhere. So you could just as easily write:

```
SomeClass::Construct()
{
    IListener* pListener = const_cast<IListener*>(*Singleton::GetInstance());
}
```

Although this still doesn't really help you. One thing it does do is make your interface a bit clearer. You see, when you write `SomeClass::Construct(const IListener&listener)` anyone reading your could reasonably imply that `listener` is treated as `const` within the function and by using `const_cast`, you've broken that implied contract. **This is a very good reason that you should not use `const_cast`** - at least not in these circumstances.

**The fundamental question that you need to ask yourself is when your `IListener` is const, why do you need to use it in a non-const way within `Construct`?** Either the singleton should not return a const object or your function should not need it to be non-const.

This is a design issue that you need to sort out before you take any further steps.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply, I have absolutely no control over Construct Method. its An API of a platform. I have just made an application which passes the singleton reference so that i can handle call back anywhere in the application.what I wanted to know was can we perform const_cast on a static pointer?

Comment: So are you saying that you are stuck with someone elses code which takes a const reference and then casts away the constness to make it a non-const pointer? If so you should tell them how very poor their code is and you should ask them to change it for the reasons mentioned above. As to your question, there is no difference in applying `const_cast` to a static pointer.

Answer (score 11):

So let me see. You have two-phase initialization, a Singleton, *and* casting away `const`, *and* you're de-referencing an object just to take it's address again? A stray NULL pointer is the *least* of your concerns, my friend.

Throw it away and write it again from scratch. And pick up a C++ book first.

Just so you know, `const_cast` cannot produce a null pointer unless it was passed one. `GetInstance()` must be returning `NULL` to produce this behaviour, which is formally UB as soon as you de-reference it.

Comment: Although this doesn't remotely answer the question, I couldn't help but +1.

Comment: GetInstance() is not returning null. I checked it. I need to derefer because Constuct takes a reference as parameter. Could you please suggest correct way of doing this? I am new to programing.

Comment: @DeadMG:Thanks for your reply, I have absolutely no control over Construct Method. its An API of a platform. I have just made an application which passes the singleton reference so that i can handle call back anywhere in the application.what I wanted to know was can we perform const_cast on a static pointer? – yogesh singh 36 secs ago

Answer (score 1):

const_cast is basically an instruction to the compiler to ignore the constness of something. Use of it is to be avoided, because you are overriding the compiler protection, and it can lead to a crash as you write something that attempts to update read-only memory.

However, it doesn't actually cause any code to be generated.

Therefore, if this:

```
IListener* pListener = const_cast<IListener*>(&listener);
```

results in pListener being NULL, then &listener is NULL, which is impossible (or you are returning a null reference for your singleton, or you are missing something out from your description of the problem).

Having said which I agree strongly with the answer from DeadMG.

Creating an empty object and doing an Init on it (2-phase construction) is to be avoided. Properly created objects should be valid, and if you have an Init method, it isn't.

Removing the constness from anything is to be avoided - it is extremely likely to produce surprising behaviour.

The amount of de-and-rereferencing in that code is going to give anyone a headache.

Comment: You should probably mention who wrote "the above answer" is, because the order shifts around sometimes.

Comment: oh, yeah, I forgot it did that. Thanks

Comment: @RyanAmos:Thanks for your reply, I have absolutely no control over Construct Method. its An API of a platform. I have just made an application which passes the singleton reference so that i can handle call back anywhere in the application.what I wanted to know was can we perform const_cast on a static pointer? – yogesh singh 36 secs ago

Comment: you can perform const_cast on a static pointer. However, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @TomTanner: I have debugged and checked. My singleton is not returning null. It is only after casting it becomes null. I just want to know what makes that happen?

Comment: const_cast will not change the value of the pointer. You are missing something else.